# Conditional Formatting for all columns in a tablix in SSRS 2008 R2

Tags: reporting-services, formatting, conditional-statements

My Requirement is to generate a validation Report with 10 columns. In parameters user will select the column name and Validation type(NULL, Blank). now i would like to highlight the null and blank cells for better focus.

I used this expression =Switch(Me.Value = "","Blue",IsNothing(Me.value),"Red") on the Background color properties after selecting the whole detail column in tablix. It is painting blue for Null records but blank records do not have an color change.

Can you please help me in this regards...

Comment: just try by changing the order like =Switch(IsNothing(Me.value),"Red",Me.Value = "","Blue")

Comment: Try testing the Length for 0?  Are you certain the blanks are truly blank, and not invisible space characters?